# $\langle v,w\rangle \cdot \langle w,v\rangle = |\langle v,w\rangle|^2$ proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I can't seem to prove this identity I have been given:

$\langle v,w\rangle \cdot \langle w,v\rangle = |\langle v,w\rangle|^2$

Could you please outline how to go about it?

Comment: Perhaps you could prove that $<v,w> = <w,v>$?

Comment: They don't necessarily, the problem sheet says it is over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and doesn't specify whether it is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Oh I did not realize that. I am sorry for the incorrect suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just from the definition of the hermitian product

$$\overline{\langle v,w\rangle}=\langle w,v\rangle$$

and for $z\in\Bbb C$, $z\overline z=\vert z\vert^2$.

Comment: How do you get that $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$? Surely $z\bar{z}=a^2+b^2\neq |z^2|$ for $z=a+bi$

Comment: @BenHarvey Note that $|z^2|$ and $|z|^2$ are two different things. $|z|$ is defined as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.